# Is it a good practice to use getDerivedStateFromProps to map props to the data structure used by render()

Tags: reactjs

I need to calculate derived state from my props so it can be used in `render()`. Is it a good practice to use getDerivedStateFromProps for this? Please look at `Adder` component to see what I mean. Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x3237294oq

```js
const sum = ({ x, y }) => x + y;

class Adder extends React.Component {
  state = { sum: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return { sum: sum(props), x: props.x, y: props.y };
  }
  render() {
    const { sum, x, y } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          {x} + {y} ={" "}
        </h3>
        <h1 style={{ color: "green" }}>{sum}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState(state => ({ x: state.x + 1 }))}>
          Increase left parameter
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState(state => ({ y: state.y + 1 }))}>
          Increase right parameter
        </button>
        <Adder x={this.state.x} y={this.state.y} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I see this pattern in the codebase I work on and I would like to understand the pros and cons of doing things this way or if it is idiomatic react at all.

Comment: If you are just going to use the state derived from the props and not manipulate it in any way, you might just as well use props directly and save you some trouble.

Comment: The state is just used, not manipulated by any means.

Comment: Then you can use `const { x, y } = this.props; const s = sum(this.props);` in the render method instead and the component will keep itself up to date with the props given to it automatically.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's what I would do as well. But I see a lot of this pattern with getDerivedStateFromProps in a codebase I work in and trying to understand if this good or bad practice? Maybe it is done this way for performance or maintainability reasons or something?

Comment: It can be useful in certain cases when you need to manipulate the state in the component but you also want changes in the props to manipulate the state. If it's just a matter of copying the props and not manipulating it further, I would say it's bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code here, the best practice would be to make your Adder component as a Presentational Component or a Stateless component. I don't think there is any need to make `Adder` here a stateful component. In most the cases you will not need the `getDerivedStateFromProps`. As per the react documentation:

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for implementing a  component that compares its previous and next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.

You can have a read at the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) of React to understand the lifecycles methods.

For more information on Presentational and Container Components, have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).